# Cannot remove SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I was in the process of installing SQL Server 2012 x64 Express Management Studio and encountered one heck of an issue.

I was most of the way through the installation process when my computer locked up and I had to do a hard restart.

Now, the computer seems to think that I have components of SQL Server 2012 installed when in reality I do not.

I tried going to the control panel and removing the components but most of the way through the removal process I get the following error:

> "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1 Setup
>
> The following error has occurred:
>
> SQL Server Setup has encountered an error when running a Windows Installer file.
>
> Windows Installer error message: This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package.
>
> Windows Installer file: {A7037EB2-F953-4B12-B843-195F4D988DA1}
>   Windows Installer log file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log>\20140813_121519\sql_ssms_Cpu64_1.log
>
> Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel this action and continue setup.
>   For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.3128.0&EvtType=0xDC80C325"

I've spent a couple hours on several days looking around for a fix to this but I haven't been able to locate a solution as of yet.

Comment: You may have to look at [this post for a brute force approach](https://sqlblog.org/2010/10/25/fun-with-software-uninstalling-sql-server-2008-r2-evaluation-edition).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I read the article and though it was a bit more than I'm comfortable with let me see if I get the gist right. You located the GUIDs which are related to the software, and which are registry keys? and then you used the msiexec /x command to uninstall them. Then that let you initiate a new install? The problem with a new install currently is that it shows 2 components still installed and so I can't install over them.

Comment: Right, msiexec /x uninstalls those components even if you no longer have the MSI.

Comment: Hi Can you upload content of C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log>\20140813_121519\sql_ssms_Cpu64_1.log on shared drive for analysis. I will do it for you seems like windows installer is corrupted due to hardboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue. I wasn't able to uninstall SQL Server but I downloaded an installer, converted it to a .zip and extracted it and then pointed the setup to that as the install media. Doing this I was able to get Management Studio up and running.

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You could follow below suggestion to check whether windows installer is in consistent state.

```
Go to run and type services.msc

scroll to Windows Installer services

Double click to bring up the service.
```

Check to see if the startup type is set to Manual.Service status is usually stopped. Try and start the Windows Installer server.Also open CMD as administrator and in CMD type below commands

```
msiexec.exe /unregister, and then press ENTER.

msiexec.exe /regserver, and then press ENTER.
```

If above works fine IMO your windows installer should not be corrupt but if you still face issue you should refer to This [Microsoft Support Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969052/en-us) which has details about how to proceed with corrupt installer.

This error can also come if installation media is corrupt. So i would like you to copy setup again and start a fresh installation by right click on Setup file and select run as administrator

Hope this helps